# SQL Server JOIN Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm trying to pull out some information from a SQL Server database (using SQL Server Management Studio) like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( t1.accountid ), 
               t1.accountname, 
               t1.reseller, 
               (SELECT t1.reseller 
                FROM   dbname t1 
                       INNER JOIN dbname t2 
                               ON t1.reseller = t2.reseller 
                WHERE  t1.reseller IN ( 1 )) AS Reseller 
FROM   dbname t1, 
       dbname t2
```

Running this gives me an error of:

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

After much research I am still stumped. And help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!)

Comment: If the reseller matches in both tables, what is the point of outputting it twice? Also why are you joining explicitly in the subquery, and then *again* but ***implicitly*** ([this is bad!](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx)) in the outer query?

Comment: Also, what is the point of the self-join AT ALL? Can you show a few rows of sample data and desired results? I started formulating an answer but there is so much wrong with your initial attempt that it is impossible to determine what this query is actually supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't apply `DISTINCT` to a single column, and I'm not sure it is needed here at all unless your table allows duplicate values across all of these columns.
2. I don't know why you're joining these tables twice, or using a subquery at all.
3. I don't know why you want to output `t1.reseller` twice ... even if you used one from `t1` and one from `t2`, since they are matching on the join, they would always be the same for every row!
4. You have an implicit join *and* you are missing a where clause - which leads to a Cartesian product and is [exactly why I always recommend against this syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Perhaps this is what triggered the use of `DISTINCT`?
5. You don't seem to be using any columns at all from t2. What is the point of the (double) self-join?

Seems like all you need is:

```
SELECT accountid, accountname, reseller
  FROM dbo.dbname
  WHERE reseller = 1;
```

Otherwise please describe exactly what your query is supposed to do (by showing sample data and desired results).

Answer (score 0):

add TOP 1 clause in subquery

as below

```
       (SELECT TOP 1 t1.reseller 
        FROM   dbname t1 
               INNER JOIN dbname t2 
                       ON t1.reseller = t2.reseller 
        WHERE  t1.reseller IN ( 1 )) AS Reseller)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error you're getting is because this query:

```
           (SELECT t1.reseller 
            FROM   dbname t1 
                   INNER JOIN dbname t2 
                           ON t1.reseller = t2.reseller 
            WHERE  t1.reseller IN ( 1 )) AS Reseller)
```

Is returning more than one value.

Comment: Wouldn't an answer also usually propose how to fix it? Other than the code block this feels like a comment to me.